# Problem in assigning of dynamic memory with dereference operator

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the second `for` loop doesn't access my dynamic memory well.

After I exit the loop, the dynamic memory will somehow lose its data, while if I use the "second method" it will be ok.

Could you explain to me why is that?

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* foo;
    foo = new (std::nothrow) int[3];
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i != 3; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> temp;
        *foo = temp;
        foo++;
        //std::cin >> foo[i];// second method (instead of line 10,11 and 12)
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != 3; i++)
        std::cout << *(foo+i) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: think about what `foo++` in the first loop does for `foo` in the second one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you allocate the array and assign its starting address to `foo`, you are incrementing `foo` in the 1st loop to access each `int` in the array.  By the time you get to the second loop, `foo` is now pointing past the end of the array.  That is why your 2nd loop cannot access the values correctly.

Your "second method" does not increment `foo` at all, so it remains pointing at the start of the array at all times.

To make your "first method" work correctly, use a separate pointer for the iteration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* foo = new (std::nothrow) int[3];
    int* ptr = foo; // <-- ADD THIS

    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> temp;
        *ptr = temp;
        ++ptr;

        //std::cin >> foo[i];// second method
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        std::cout << *(foo+i) << std::endl;

    delete[] foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any time you're writing a loop with an index variable, and not actually using that index variable in the body of the loop, it's not _necessarily_ wrong, but it should at least raise questions about your logic.